# ABAP Objects - access message class of a class?

Tags: abap

In the header information of an ABAP Objects class, I can enter a message class to use with the `MESSAGE` statement. This works like the `MESSAGE-ID` statement of a report or a function pool. Since I can't find the message class I entered in the header data anywhere in the generated sections, I assume that it's generated into the top-level [`CLASS-POOL`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCLASS-POOL.htm) statement somewhere.

For some libraries (for examples, the BAL application logging), it's necessary to specify the message class using a variable or a method parameter. Up to now, I've defined a constant that specified the message class and used that constant. I'm wondering if it's possible to access the message class specified in the header data in some other way so that I can get rid of that redundant variable.

Has anyone found a way to do so?

**EDIT:** The new way should be easier than the old one - I'm not crazy enough to add a `CLASS-CONSTRUCTOR` and perform some database access or `SEO_*` function calls just to get rid of that constant.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need a `CLASS-CONSTRUCTOR` to set a class attribute with the message class.

The `MESSAGE` statement with `INTO` clause has the side effect of setting the `SY-` system variables. So you could put into your `CLASS-CONSTRUCTOR` something like:

```
DATA: lf_dummy TYPE string.
MESSAGE s999 INTO lf_dummy.
af_msgid = sy-msgid.
```

Comment: This is IMHO worse than defining a constant, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually it is not that bad, especially if you use to pass it later to BAL APIs. Point is that the message passed into BAL as parameter value is not found by where-used-lists, but if you first raise the message using MESSAGE statement and then you feed BAL APIs with SY-MSG* values, your usage got captured by where-used-lists...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't come across any syntax to do what you ask. For the reasons I outline below, I could believe that SAP never saw a need to include such functionality.

In my experience, the message class is an attribute of the message, not of the object that raises it, so it should be kept together with the type,  number, and variables of the message. For example if my object is returning the number of an error, it should be returning the id (class) as well.

In this light I cannot see a reason why you would ever need to know the message-class assigned to an ABAP-OO class, you would only ever need to know the message-class of the messages returned by the ABAP-OO class.

The way I usually manage this is to raise my messages into a dummy field, and then use a subroutine to populate the contents of the `sy-msg*` fields into a `BAPIRETURN` structure. Then I return this `BAPIRETURN` structure to the caller. This way the type, id, number, and variables of the message are all kept together.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the class builder API:

```
data the_class type ref to cl_oo_class.
create object the_class
  exporting
    clsname = `ZCL_SOMECLASS`.
data message_class type arbgb.
message_class = the_class->class-msg_id.
```